# Can I restore a SQL Server 2005 backup on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I'm setting up a dev. environment and my production environment has SQL Server 2005. I was wondering if I will be able to restore 2005 .bak files into the 2008 server. I just need the initial restore then I can script everything else.

Is it possible to restore a 2005 backup in 2008?

Comment: Theres a [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. MS-SQL is backward compatible.
Just try.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not the other way around.